# C linked list search function

Tags: c, search, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*Define custom functions */
void insertElement();
bool elementExists();
int getNumElements();


/*Create linked list */
struct node {
    int number;
    int occurence;
    struct node *next;
};

/*Call our linked list freqTable */
struct node *freqTable = NULL;

unsigned int numElements = 0;

int main(){
    int readNumElements = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int newNum, status;

    status = scanf("%d", &readNumElements);
    if(status == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%d is not a number\n", readNumElements);
        exit(-1);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < readNumElements;i++) {
        status = scanf("%d", &newNum);
        if(status == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%d is not a number\n", newNum);
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(elementExists(newNum)){
            printf("%d exists\n", newNum);
        }else{
            insertElement(&freqTable, newNum);
        }

    }

return 0;
}

void insertElement(struct node **list, int n){
    struct node *new_input; 

    new_input = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(new_input == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Failed to create memory for new node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_input->number = n;
    new_input->occurence = 1;
    new_input->next = *list;
    numElements++;

    *list = new_input;
}

bool elementExists(int n){
    printf("%d\n", freqTable->number);
return false;
}

int getNumElements(){
    return numElements;
}
```

Ok heres what i got. This should compile.

Problem comes at

```
    if(elementExists(newNum)){
        printf("%d exists\n", newNum);
    }else{
        insertElement(&freqTable, newNum);
    }
```

I get segmentation error and i am not sure why.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: If you never allocate a node and assign it to the `freqTable` variable, you are always going to access memory location 0 + some offset, guaranteeing a segmentation fault!

Comment: I do, i have an insert function. Like it said it works in main. I can print the last element just by doing freqTable->number. I can also do freqTable->next->number and etc... I just can't do this in my elementExists funcion.

Comment: I would suggest that you post the shortest code that _should_ compile and work but produces the error.

Comment: @Matt, post at least the `insertNumber` prototype.  Probably, you should just post the whole program.

Comment: I think you removed the question in the process.

Comment: @Jeff - I did, but i just reworded it. I just want to get rid of this segmentation error first.

Comment: @Matt: If you get solution to your problem, you need not delete the program :) I've rolled back the changes.

Comment: -1 for removeing your code.now i will vote to close your qstion

Comment: @fahad fine with me, but due to academic policy i can't post it until after the project has been submitted and grade. Sorry.

Comment: @Matt: The code is already posted, it can be viewed from the revision history…

Comment: -1 for removing the code

Comment: Have you submitted for grade yet? you should either rollback so the code can be seen or delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `elementExists` you need to ensure that  freqTable is not `NULL` :

```
bool elementExists(int n){
 if(freqTable) {  // add this check
   printf("%d\n", freqTable->number);
 }
}
```

Also your `elementExists` does not do what its supposed to do(check for existence of a node with value `n`), you should do something like:

```
bool elementExists(int n) {

 if(!freqTale) { // table does not exist..return false.
  return false;
 }
 // table exists..iterate node by node and check.
 struct node *tmp = freqTable;
 while(tmp) { // loop till tmp becomes NULL
  if(*tmp == n) { // it node contains n..return false.
    return true;
   }
  tmp = tmp->next; // move on
 }
 return false; // n does not exist in the list..return false.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i found error. Hopefully this will help someone else. struct node *tmp = freqTable; I basically did struct node *tmp = &freqTable;

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the call to `elementExists`:

```
if(elementExists(&freqTable, newNum)){
```

You pass the *address* of freqTable (i.e. a pointer to where the pointer to the first element of the list is stored) instead of its value. Yet in `elementExists` you dereference the argument as though it were a pointer to a list element:

```
printf("Compare with: %d\n", list->number);
```

and

```
else list = list->next;
```

Remove the `&` from the call to `elementExists`. And don't reference the global `freqTable` inside `elementExists` if you are passing the list as an argument.

Comment: Yea noticed that after codaddicts post. Thanks. This was exactly the problem i was having. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you're dereferencing `freqTable` in `elementExists` before any nodes are allocated.  Thus, `freqTable` is always NULL, so you invoke undefined behavior.  You could just add a check for NULL in `elementExists`, and return false in that case.

Comment: your correct. Let me update it to what i want to do.